# Польза использования библиотек

Tags: android

Толком не освоив I/O в Java я использую библиотеку SimpleStorage. Также сетевые запросы реализую с помощью Retrofit. Вместо SQL юзаю ОРМ, картинки гружу через Picasso, а не руками. Скажите, что меня ждет в будущем? Стоит ли бросать библиотеки? Возможно ли что скоро на собеседованиях не будут спрашивать основы, а вместо них будут проверять на знание библиотек? Ведь это уже стало модно :)

Comment: Лично я изучал, как все работает "под капотом" и когда я понял, что изобретаю велосипеды - я начал использовать подобные библиотеки. которые экономят кучу времени. Несомненно, основу знать нужно. Но зачем отказываться от того, что сделало качественно "группа" программистов. Тот же Retrofit для конектов использует Okhttp либу, которя в свою очередь использует httpurlconnection. До знакомство с ретрофит я польщовался напрямую httpurlconnection. надоело. ибо долго самому все кастомить + иногда мозгов может нехватить. А тут комманда разработчиков поддерживает.

Comment: @Chaynik, а вы не думаете, что эти библиотеки уже сделаны для всего подряд и скоро каждый сможет написать все что захочет, даже человек, не разбирающийся в программировании. Это будет конец света :D

Comment: - так развивается наша сфера. Она не будет стоять на месте и ждать когда кто то что то изучит ). Если вы один разрабатываете программу - то писать хелперы - требует много времени + баги полюбому. - Как результат вы помогли себе, но ничего не сделали для других )

Comment: Но даже для использования библиотек нужны мозги. Так что конца света не будет. Я очень много уже прособеседовал разработчиков. Они использовали все те же библиотеки - но вы не поверите из 20 разрабов с опытом 2+ года только 20% понимают что у них под капотом и могут объяснить как они работают, а если человек не понимает, как оно устроено, я не могу сказать, что он это будет использовать эффективно. По этому по изобретайте велосипеды - а потом пользуйтесь удобными библиотеками -)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Скажите, что меня ждет в будущем? Стоит ли бросать библиотеки?

Нет, библиотеки бросать не стоит, но (имхо) нужно как минимум примерно представлять, как работают используемые Вами библиотеки (не прям всегда, но все же). Иначе, в противном случае – шаг влево, шаг вправо и все...

В приличных крупных компаниях собеседования (на джуниора, а может и на мидла) с Вами начнут не с вопросов по платформе, и даже не с вопросов по языку, а с вопросов по алгоритмам (например, те же сортировки, их вычислительная сложность и все такое) и структурам данных.

Однако же подобных компаний очень мало и на собеседованиях интервьюеры довольно часто задают вопросы, список которых есть в интернете (и это плохо). Это вопросы по языку и платформе.

> Возможно ли что скоро на собеседованиях не будут спрашивать основы, а вместо них будут проверять на знание библиотек?

Ну, проверять только лишь знание библиотек – это вряд ли.

Я считаю, что хороший программист, в первую очередь, должен знать теорию по алгоритмам, после этого уже сам язык, а потом уже всякие библиотеки и фреймворки.

Резюмируя, скажу: по-моему мнению, сначала (при обучении) нужно написать свой велосипед, а уже потом, в продакшене, использовать готовые и протестированные сторонние средства.

Answer (score 9):

По опыту знаю, что многое зависит от библиотеки и от проекта. Я сам работал в компаниях, где либо используют "модные" библиотеки, либо не используют почти никаких. И везде есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Далее **мое личное мнение**:

1. Грань между "стоит залезть под капот" и "не стоит писать велосипед". Тут могу только на примерах:

   - Лезть в Retrofit, не понимая, как создавать различные HTTP запросы (да и в принципе без достаточно хорошего понимания того, как это работает), - не стоит. Лучше сначала поработать с HttpUrlConnection, потом с OkHttp. Разберетесь в тонкостях, а также поразмышляете над тем, как грамотно оборачивать запросы в асинхронку.
   - Picasso/Glide/etc. Если Вы понимаете, как происходит передача файлов по сети, то мучиться над созданием грамотного image loader-a на мой взгляд не стоит (конечно, если у Вас нет академического интереса). Инструменты написаны, работают грамотно.
   - ORM. Если Вы знакомы с SQL, почувствовали хотя бы чутка процесс создания хелперов руками, то смело используйте ORM. Избавит Вас от написания примитивной кучи кода и освободит время, которое бы Вы тратили на обдумывания, как архитектурно эту кучу кода представить.
   - I/O освоить надо. Тут я думаю просто все согласятся. Просто. Надо.
   - RxJava. Вот тут холивар. Мне кажется, что если подключать Rx, то использовать реактивный подход по максимуму в модели. Подключать такую не малую библиотеку ради маппинга в нескольких экранах или просто ради асинхронных блоков - не гуд.
2. Грань между велосипедом и подтягиванием библиотекой с кучей кода, которая немного упрощает разработку и утяжеляет проект. Выше я писал про Rx - к этому пункту тоже касается. Я видел много проектов, где подключаются новомодные библиотеки, типа Dagger 2, RxJava, Mosby/Moxy и т.д., а применяются всего в паре мест: даггером инжектят всего 2-3 зависимости в 4-5 местах максимум, RxJava используют ради асинхронки, ну а Mosby/Moxy на 4-5 экранах... Результат такой, что приложение из 5 экранов, отображающее простые списки с данными и имеющее небольшой функционал, весит 20+ Мб. В продакшене размер apk имеет значение.

На собеседованиях меня спрашивали как о библиотеках, так и о том, что под капотом. Но если выяснится (по крайней мере сейчас), что Вы знаете, как использовать библиотеку, но не сможете при необходимости написать в меру качественное решение задачи без нее, то это провал.

Самые интересные вопросы были из рода: как бы вы решили такую-то задачу средствами Android SDK или Java -> с какими бы трудностями могли столкнуться -> какую бы библиотеку применили в качестве альтернативы -> какие трудности могут появиться в таком решении.

Библиотеки могут быть сколь угодно модными, но на работу же принимают разработчика, а не тупо кодера. А разработчик должен уметь думать и разбираться во внутренностях.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, только абзац последний какой раз перечитываю и не пойму никак - разве кодер и разработчик это не одно и то же?

Comment: Кодеру дали узкую задачу, смысл которой заключается в том, чтобы написать рабочий код в рамках этой узкой задачи, без вопросов. Разработчик прежде всего думает, предлагает альтернативные решения, проявляет инициативу, а потом уже кодит.

Comment: A что вы думаете про Anko?

Comment: @Соколов ничего не думаю. Я ее не использовал не разу. Могу сказать, что я предпочитаю верстать в инструментах для верстки. Но Anko выигрывает в производительности, так как не используется inflate  и рефлексия в findViewById, но чтобы заметить этот выйгрыш, нужно написать нечто очень замудренное.